# APK build with ReactNative Can't be Replaced with APK build with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have an apk released in playstore which is built using React-Native. Now, I wanted to build the same project using the Android Studio. The package name and app id is same, the keystore is also same. But, whenever I try to install a newer apk (built with Android Studio) over the old apk(built with React-Native) it says apk is not installed.

Is there someone faced the same same problem? Or, may some one can help me there? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please uninstall previously installed apk then install new apk

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, sorry that's not a solution. I need to update the apk also in the play store

Comment: @ArhanAshik Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed. When I built the final signed apk and uploaded it to playstore it replaced the old apk without any trouble. Thanks everyone for help. :)

Comment: I did not need a solution. It was updated automatically when I uploaded the new version. It is just a problem for development time. Okay with deployment. @KRK

Answer (score 0):

if the package is same then this happens only because of difference of buildtype. either you are installing debug apk over signed apk and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I have tried with both buildtype. It's not working. Although I am sure the buildtype is Release Build. Because the previous one is already on the playstore.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed. When I built the final signed apk and uploaded it to playstore it replaced the old apk without any trouble. Thanks everyone for help. :)