# How to replace React Native Android APK with a Native Android APK on update?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have developed an app using React Native which is available in the Playstore. Now I am migrating the codebase to Native Android. When I try to install the APK built with Native Android as an update, I get an error saying - APK is not installed. I have used the same package name, application name and signing credentials. I have also bumped up the version number in the Native Android APK.

I have referred this link - [APK build with ReactNative Can't be Replaced with APK build with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759959/apk-build-with-reactnative-cant-be-replaced-with-apk-build-with-android-studio).

But no solution has been mentioned here either.

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct packageName? Better check on device which app packages are installed: execute `adb shell pm list packages` and check if your package name is really installed.

Comment: Thank you for the response Robert, I checked it with the command you've provided. Both the package names are the same.

Comment: How do you install the APK file? Make sure you do it using `adb install -r <app.apk>`. It it does not work you are getting the most detailed error message.

Comment: Robert, I need to send the new app as an update via the Playstore. Will that cause any issues during update? After the update, will the data of the previous React native app remain in the device so that I can fetch it from the Native Android app?

Comment: Google does not "diff" your apps. As long as package name and signature remains the same it is the same app (from Google perspective) and therefore the data is not deleted on update. I would recommend to test that on your own by publishing your new native app as (closed) beta version to some test devices that were equipped with the react-native version before.